# Parse JSON with GSON without a model

Tags: java, json, gson

Suppose you have a JSON object:

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "s54dsf45fzd324": "135sdq13sod1tt3",
    "21sm24dsfp2ds2": "123sd56f4gt4ju4"
  }
}
```

The only thing you know about the mappings object is that it maps strings to strings, but you do not know the key values.

Is it possible to parse this object with GSON and cycle through the key/value pairs?

Comment: This is what one would (in any other language) simply refer to as "parsing" the JSON.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply try with `TypeToken` that will return a `Map<String, Map<String, String>>` as Type.

```
Reader reader=new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File("resources/json.txt")));

Type type = new TypeToken<Map<String, Map<String, String>>>() {}.getType();
Map<String, Map<String, String>> data = new Gson().fromJson(reader, type);

// pretty printing 
System.out.println(new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create().toJson(data));
```

output:

```
{
    "mappings": {
      "s54dsf45fzd324": "135sdq13sod1tt3",
      "21sm24dsfp2ds2": "123sd56f4gt4ju4"
    }
}
```

Comment: and what about `{"field":"value", "mappings":{"key":"value"}}`, e.g. if other fields may take on other values?

Comment: Try with `Type type = new TypeToken<Map<String, Object>>() {}.getType(); Map<String, Object> data = gson.fromJson(reader, type);` at high level.

Comment: First value is `String` and second value is `Map<String, String>` in the resultant map.

Comment: And then `data.get("mappings")` will return a `Map<String,String>`?

Comment: yes it will return the `Object` then just downcast to `Map<String,String>` after checking.

Answer (score 1):

With Java 8+ and without TypeToken:

```java
    new Gson().fromJson(jsonString, JsonObject.class).getAsJsonObject("mappings")
    .entrySet().stream().forEach(System.out::println);
```